# editar variável local fora da função

Tags: python, python-3.x, variáveis, global

Olá! Como faço para alterar uma variável local de uma função por comandos externos a função?
Exemplo:

Criar a função

```
def totalValue(type):
    try:
        valor = float(texto[0])
    except:
         valor = 0
    total = str(float(valor))
    if type == 1:
        return valor
    elif type == 2:
        return total
```

"texto[0]" se trata de um valor salvo em um arquivo txt utilizado como banco de dados local.

Durante a execução do código é necessário atualizar o valor de total.
exemple:

```
total = totalValue(2) + 200
```

A dúvida é como consigo alterar o valor de uma variável local de uma função, no caso "total", estando no corpo do programa ou em outras funções.

Comment: Melhor dizer o que **precisa** fazer porque isto está completamente errado (vários erros juntos), parece ter um problema XY aí e não precisa do que está perguntando, portanto a solução é outra.

Comment: No exemplo que você deu, totalValue(2) retorna uma *string*, que geraria um erro quando somada a 200.

Comment: Na verdade eu cortei algumas partes do programa, porque esses valores dependem de outras variáveis. escrevi dessa forma apenas para ilustrar

Comment: no quesito de erro sintático ou semântico, o programa original não apresenta erros.

Comment: Realmente o problema não está suficientemente claro e o que é perguntado de fato se parece com um poema XY. Consegue detalhar melhor o que quer fazer? Parece-me que ao invés de usar variáveis globais você poderia criar uma classe e gerenciar o contexto corretamente a partir dela. Com variáveis globais, se não souber o que está fazendo, o problema do se agravará, mesmo que pareça que resolva inicialmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na variável `valor` você pode passar uma `string` recuperada de um arquivo de texto, contanto que seja um valor numérico ou passar esta `string` diretamente como parâmetro na função `calcular_total`. Esta função irá incrementar a variável global chamada `total`.

```
valor = "10.5"

total = 0

def calcular_total(valor):

    global total    

    total += float(valor)

    return total


total = calcular_total(valor)
total = calcular_total("0.5")
total = calcular_total("1.8")

print(total)
```

Saída:

`12.8`

Comment: Obrigado! Deu certo.

Comment: Que bom Jorge, fico feliz em te ajudar. Abraço e até a próxima!